# Set data in another user's column

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I would like to add someone on one account, and it puts the person's username in the other person's relations. I was wondering how I could do this. When person 1 adds person 2, it adds person 1's relation in person 2's account. Then, person 2 can accept the person and both get added in each other's friendsRelation.

How would I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a `FriendRequest` class, and a `User.friends` property on each user (either array or Relation, depending how many you expect, probably a Relation).

```
FriendRequest
.fromUser (user)
.toUser (user)
.status (string: 'pending', 'rejected', etc
```

When someone requests a friendship, it adds a row (would check if there's an existing row first, an existing 'rejected' row would block the request).

This lets you easily show a user all their pending requests (requestQuery.equalTo('fromUser', currentUser) for JavaScript). You can also show a use all invitations (requestQuery.equalTo('toUser', currentUser) and requestQuery.equalTo('status', 'pending')). When a user accepts, you update the status to 'accepted' and add each user to each others 'friends' list.

You could also then add a feature to show who you've blocked (status = 'rejected' or status = 'unfriended' for example) and allow you to unblock them.

The process of un-friending someone would be a matter of removing them from each others friends list and finding the record in FriendRequest (would need to use an or query on `fromUser` and `toUser`) and updated it to 'unfriended' status.

Comment: Yeah but that only adds the friend on one account. How do I make it so currentUser and friendUser both get added in each others relations.